# How to remove text both sides of character?

Tags: r, regex

How can I transform a column of characters written as

```
c("0 y", "0 m", "23 d", "0 y",  "0 m", "8 d")
```

into number values

```
c(0, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0)
```

example of what I'm talking about

[image]

another example that has some single-digit dates

[image]

Comment: If you have `1 y 2 m 8d` etc. what value would be for year

Comment: Try `gsub("^.*(\\d+) d.*$", "\\1", x)` where x is you vector of strings

Comment: It is almost always preferable to add code and data as formatted text to the question than to use pictures of code and data. Also a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) is always weclome! Although in this really simple case it might not be really necessary.

Comment: the answers never include months or years, its a short term follow up value, hope that clears it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` to capture the digits before the space followed by 'd'

```
as.integer(sub(".*\\s(\\d+) d", "\\1", v1))
#[[1] 12 13 12 15 12
```

---

Or with `regmatches/regexpr`

```
regmatches(v1, regexpr("(\\d+)(?= d$)", v1, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "12" "13" "12" "15" "12"
```

---

If we need to convert to all days, then

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(col1 = v1) %>% 
  tidyr::extract(col1, into = c('year', 'month', 'day'),
       "^(\\d+) y, (\\d+) m, (\\d+) d$",  convert = TRUE) %>% 
  transmute(days = year * 365 + month * 30 + day)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("0 y, 0 m, 12 d", "0 y, 0 m, 13 d", "0 y, 0 m, 12 d",
        "0 y, 0 m, 15 d", "1 y, 2 m, 12 d")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming y and m are always 0

```
Oy.date.diff <- c("0 y, 0 m, 12 d", "0 y, 0 m, 13 d", "0 y, 0 m, 12 d", "0 y, 0 m, 15 d") 
as.numeric(gsub(" d", "", gsub("0 y, 0 m, ", "", Oy.date.diff)))
# [1] 12 13 12 15
```

Note that R does not allow variables (or columns) to begin with a digit so the first character is uppercase letter O.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this capturing regex with gsub, which captures any numbers before a " d" and doesn't make any assumptions about the rest of the string:

```
x <- c("0 y, 0 m, 12 d", "0 y, 0 m, 13 d", "0 y, 0 m, 12 d", "0 y, 0 m, 15 d") 
gsub("^.*(\\d+) d.*$", "\\1", x)
#> [1] "2" "3" "2" "5"
```